# operación delete Node js

Tags: nodejs

Hola gente estoy haciendo un CRUD de ejemplo con Node js y resulta que cuando quiero hacer un DELETE el postman me dice que fue eliminado con éxito pero luego al hacer un GET a ese Id me sigue devolviendo los datos (lo mismo, si listo todas las películas, aparece la que fue eliminada).
Adjunto el código:

```
app.get('/peliculas',(req,res)=>{

Movie.find({},(err,movies)=>{
    if((err)) return res.status(500).send({message: "Error al procesar la peticion"})
    if(!movies) return res.status(404).send({message: "No hay peliculas"})
    res.status(200).send({movies: movies})    
})


})

app.delete('/peliculas/:peliculaId',(req,res)=>{

    let movieId = req.params.movieId;

    Movie.findByIdAndRemove(movieId, (err, todo) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        const response = {
            message: "Pelicula eliminada con éxito",
            id: res.movieId
        };
        return res.status(200).send(response);

    })
})
```

Comment: Puedes ver lo que devuelve la variable `todo` que recibe tu función callback? Es posible que la operación de modificación (`remove`) no se esté realizando. Estás capturando sólo si hay un error en la consulta, pero no capturas el caso en que `todo` devuelva `null` o `undefined` o un objeto vacío, etc. Simplemente asumes que si no devuelve error entonces todo va bien, lo cual no es necesariamente cierto. Saludos

Comment: hice un par de ajustes, agregué la linea if(!todo) return res.status(404).send({message:"Pelicula no encontrada"}) , de todas formas el error era que habia nombrado el parametro como "peliculaId" y despues lo obtenia con otro nombre (movieId), me traspapelé con eso anoche jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nombre del parametro no es el mismo, en la url usas `/:peliculaId` y al momento de obtener el parametro usas `movieId`.

Aqui cambio el nombre del parametro de `:peliculaId` a `:movieId`.

```
app.delete('/peliculas/:movieId',(req,res)=>{

    let movieId = req.params.movieId;

    Movie.findByIdAndRemove(movieId, (err, todo) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        const response = {
            message: "Pelicula eliminada con éxito",
            id: res.movieId
        };
        return res.status(200).send(response);

    })
})
```